# How to select a MAX value from column in Query Builder in Kohana framework?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.2, query-builder

I need to `INSERT` a data to `table`, but before a query I must to know the `MAX` value from column `position`, than to `INSERT` a data WHERE my `SELECTED before position+1`. Is it possible with query builder?

following my first comment I did  query:

```
$p = DB::select(array(DB::expr('MAX(`position`)', 'p')))->from('supercategories')->execute();

echo $p;
```

the error:

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined offset: 1

MODPATH\database\classes\kohana\database.php [ 505 ]

500      */
501     public function quote_column($column)
502     {
503         if (is_array($column))
504         {
505             list($column, $alias) = $column;
506         }
507 
508         if ($column instanceof Database_Query)
509         {
510             // Create a sub-query
```

**upd**

```
$p = DB::select(array(DB::expr('MAX(position)'), 'p'))->from('supercategories')->execute();
```

I used this. But how to get a result?

**Solution**

```
$p = DB::select(array(DB::expr('MAX(position)'), 'p'))->from('supercategories')->execute()->get('p');
```

Comment: `->select(array(DB::expr('MAX(column_name)', 'alias')))`

Comment: "select(array(DB::expr('MAX(`position`)'), 'p'))" --- oops, missed the 'p' argument position. Try now?

Comment: it is returns me an object, but how to get a value, `$p->p` or `$p->position` ?

Comment: add `->get('p')` after `execute()` or you could use `$p->p` - it should work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total solution would look like:

1. `DB::select(array(DB::expr('MAX(position)'), 'p'))`
2. To retrieve the value use `get('p')` or the `$result->p`